# How to unit test retrofit call?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit2

For Example I have a retrofit interface such as:

```
interface SampleService {
    fun getSomething(@body someBody: SomeBody)
}
```

Now I have a class which uses this interface such as:

```
class UserRequester(val service: SampleService) {
     fun doGetSomething(someValue: String) {
         val response = service.getSomething(SomeBody(someValue))
         // ...
     }
 }
```

I want to test this class but dont know how to mock it.

I'm trying the following:

```
val mockSampleService = mock()
val userRequester = UserRequester(mockSampleService)
val requestBody = SomeBody(someString))
  when(mockSampleService.getSomething(requestBody)).return(myExpectedValue)
....
```

My problem is that since I create the request object inside the function, I could not make the mock when().thenReturn() to work since i am technically passing two different object.

How should I test this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mockito allows you to match any argument. Read more:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any()

Comment: `service.getSomething(SomeBody(someValue))` here you have a static dependency on `SomeBody`, you could pass a `SomeBodyFactory` to `UserRequester`

Comment: @lelloma Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: To all those who answered my question thank you very much :D this helped alot :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The mocking problem (UserRequester)**

You are not able to mock the `mockSampleService` method because your class is creating the `SomeBody` object and is different from the `SomeBody` object you are creating in your test.

Now you have 2 options:

1. Use `Mockito.any()` in your test, in this way you basically say that whatever your method is gonna use as parameter you will return the mocked behaviour
2. Use a factory that given a `someString` returns you a `SomeObject` like this:

```
// the factory
class SomeObjectFactory{

    fun createSomeObject(someString: String): SomeObject {
        return SomeObject(someString)
    }

}

//the class
class UserRequester(
val service: SampleService, val factory: SomeObjectFactory
) {
     fun doGetSomething(someValue: String) {
         val response = service.getSomething(factory.createSomeObject(someValue))
         // ...
     }
 }

//the test
class MyTest{

    @Test
    fun myTestMethod(){
        val mockSampleService = mock()
        val factory = mock()
        val someBody = mock()
        val userRequester = UserRequester(mockSampleService, factory)
        `when`(factory.createSomeObject(someString)).thenReturn(someBody)

  `when`(mockSampleService.getSomething(someBody)).thenReturn(myExpectedValue)
    //rest of the code
    }

}
```

The second approach is the cleanest one.

**Testing Retrofit calls (SampleService)**

I wouldn't `unit test` a Retrofit call.

When you are dealing with frameworks, apis, databases, shared preferences is always preferable to do `integration tests` instead of `unit tests`.

In this way you are actually testing that your code is working with the outside world.

I suggest you to test Retrofit calls with [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) (it's a library from `Square`, the same company that developed OkHttp and Retrofit).

This [read](https://android.jlelse.eu/unit-test-api-calls-with-mockwebserver-d4fab11de847) may be also helpful.

Comment: It's not the Retrofit call the OP wants to test but the `UserRequester` implementation, which might have complex, unit testable business logic, and which depends on the `SampleService` interface, not on Retrofit.

Comment: you are right! I got confused by the title, I will update my answer :)

Comment: I think it's overkill to define a separate factory interface and implementation for *every* call that needs some wrapped value. You don't need to resort to the `any` matcher either, you can use the `argThat` matcher (see usage in my answer).

Comment: @JanosBreuer true, that could be the 3rd option.
But the 2nd one I proposed is the correct one. 
First in unit testing except the class under test everything should be mocked, in the way you proposed or with `any` your class knows about the implementation of another class. 
Second it is not an overkill, if `SomeBody` changes its constructor and you are creating an instance of it in several classes now all your tests and classes are broken, with the factory instead you have only 1 class to update.

Comment: By overkill I mean you will have as many factories as the number of ways you can convert value objects to other value objects. Factories are useful when you want to create an instance of an **interface** without exposing the concrete implementation class. `SomeBody` is not an interface, its creation shouldn't be hidden, what's more it should be tested that it wraps `someValue` correctly.

Comment: Factories create objects not just instances of interfaces. Anyway if you don't like the factory you can use a mapper (from something to dto). Also that is a DTO not a value object

Answer (score 2):

Probably `SomeBody` is a plain value object, since Retrofit requests work with value objects. If you define the `equals` method for the `SomeBody` class then the `eq` matcher will work, and you can write using [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying):

```
whenever(mockService.getSomething(eq(SomeBody(someString)))).thenReturn(stubbedResult)
```

Actually, you can omit the `eq` matcher, Mockito will use the `equals` method for matching.

If `SomeBody` is a Kotlin `data class` then the `equals` method is automatically defined by comparing the fields.

If for some reason you don't want to rely on `equals`, then you can use the `argThat` matcher defined in mockito-kotlin:

```
whenever(mockService.getSomething(argThat { theField == someValue })).thenReturn(stubbedResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is static dependency on `SomeBody`'s constructor:

```
val response = service.getSomething(SomeBody(someValue))
```

What you could do to have control over the instantiation of `SomeBody` is to use a "provider" or "factory" object, you can inject it in the constructor and invoke it at the right time:

```
interface SampleService {
    fun getSomething(someBody: SomeBody)
}

open class SomeBody(val body: String)

open class UserRequester(
    val service: SampleService,
    val someBodyProvider: (String) -> SomeBody
) {

    fun doGetSomething(someValue: String) {
        val response = service.getSomething(someBodyProvider(someValue))
    }
}
```

And mock it in your tests:

```
val someValue = "foo"
val sampleService: SampleService = mock()
val someBody: SomeBody = mock()
val someBodyProvider: (String) -> SomeBody = mock {
    on { invoke(someValue) }.thenReturn(someBody)
}
val userRequester = UserRequester(sampleService, someBodyProvider)

userRequester.doGetSomething("foo")

verify(sampleService).getSomething(someBody)
verify(someBodyProvider).invoke(someValue)
```

I used an anonymous function but you might as well make it an `interface`.

Comment: With this approach, you cannot verify that the `"foo"` argument is correctly wrapped in the SomeBody object since the content of the SomeBody object is not checked.

Comment: OK, but I agree with the Mockito wiki that says that [value objects should not be mocked](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-value-objects)

Comment: OK, then don't mock them :)

Comment: @JanosBreuer what does it mean by "value objects should not be mocked". There's not much info that that wiki or maybe just dont' understant it. Can you elaborate it for me?

Comment: There's a *very* good [book](https://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627/) the Mockito wiki recommends. It says you should have these categories: 1) Value classes (i.e. POJOs) that represent values but don't have any behavior, 2) adapter classes to glue external libs/OS to your program and 3) business logic classes that work on value objects and use other business logic classess and adapters. 3) should be *unit* tested. 2) and 3) should have interfaces and mocked. 1) should not be mocked since they do not represent behavior. Check them by value in tests.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones the important bit of why mocking POJOs is not recommended is that mocking has a computation cost, in particular for classes with many methods, and just creating an instance of the actual class shouldn't be an issue because POJOs don't have any logic

Comment: thank you so much for those inputs it really helps me learn :D :D